# Is combination of squared Euclidean and normalized cosine distance follow Bregman-divergence?

Tags: metric-spaces, euclidean-algorithm, similar-matrices, bergman-spaces

I know that squared euclidean distance satisfy the property of Bregman-divergence. I wanted to do some experiments using combination of various distance metric. So I am curious to know if I add negative squared Euclidean with normalized cosine similarity; will it still hold the property of Bregman-divergence or not ?